# AppPreview: Record iOS-Simulator w/ 100% scale while showing 33% scale

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, app-preview

I want to prepare my AppPreview with the iOS iPhone 7 Plus simulator. To be able to operate the app, I need to scale 33% on my monitor. Is it possible to still output the video at 100% in order to get the best quality for the AppPreview?

Comment: How will you record it?

Comment: 'xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo video.mp4'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off 'Optimize Rendering For Window Scale' from Simulator's Debug menu to cause the buffer to be at the pixel resolution of the device.  Then, you'll be able to record in full resolution via `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo ...`

Comment: Excellent – that does it. Apple just closed a bug report with the identical info. Should really document it somewhere.

Comment: We do document it in the simulator help documentation ;).